# UITextView cuts overflow for certain fonts

Tags: swift, uitextview

When using certain script fonts, like Zapfino, `UITextView` cuts part of the lowercase letters at the line beginning. You can see this on the screenshots for the letters j and q.

I already deactivated clips to bounds, but it seems to have no effect. When the app is launched and I debug the view hierarchy it still says clips to bounds ON while all the internal subviews like textcontainers etc have clips to bounds OFF.

Is there any way to solve that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `UIEdgeInsets` for textview? It's more like a hack but I think that's can work for you. 
Example: `textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 30, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Comment: @Andrew agree this is a hack, but it is only manual. I would need a solution which would set the insets based on the font and the specific characters. Or it would figure out the maximum overflows for the respective font and then would set the insets. Not sure what would be required for that...